# Adjust web service method SQL from code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridView in asp, currently using the following datasource -

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSourceTEST" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="connection string" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM table">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

I can adjust the `SelectCommand` in the code behind by doing -

```
SqlDataSourceTEST.SelectCommand = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE ID =" + iD;
```

However I am now adjusting the code to populate the gridView through a web service method -

```
[WebMethod]

    public DataSet sMethod()
    {
        using (SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(DBcon))
        {

            string sql = "SELECT * FROM table";
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, cnn);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds, "table");

            return ds;

        }
    }
```

Then on page load populating the gridView -

```
WebService1 ws = new WebService1();
gridView1.DataSource = ws.sMethod();
gridView1.DataBind();
```

Is there a way I can adjust the `string sql` part of the web method in the code behind to add variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your `WebMethod` accept parameter:

```
public DataSet sMethod(string sql)
{
   if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(sql))
   {
       sql = "SELECT * FROM table";
   } 
   SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, cnn);

   ...
}
```

and call it from website:

```
string sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE ID =" + iD;
WebService1 ws = new WebService1();
gridView1.DataSource = ws.sMethod(sql);
gridView1.DataBind();
```

Comment: Spot on, don't know why I didn't think of that!

Answer (score 0):

[WebMethod]

```
public DataSet sMethod()
{
    using (SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(DBcon))
    {

        string sql = "SELECT * FROM table";
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, cnn);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds, "table");

        return ds;

    }
}
```